# SQL: replace string with value from a field (bulk edit)

Tags: mysql, wordpress, dynamic, replace, edit

I'm trying to figure out a way to replace a substring in a text (content) with the corresponding row value from a field (title) in a WordPress installation. So, instead of "title-xy" and "my fabulous content for that page... ", I'd like to get "my fabulous content for title-xy... ", replacing the "that page" with my title.

I know how to bulk replace, but not with a dynamic field value. DB is a MySQL with PHPMyAdmin interface.

Any help will be greatly appreciated! 
Thx,
Joerg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use MySQL's [`REPLACE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) function. A query such as this should work:

```
update myTable set content = replace(content, 'that page', title);
```

Comment: Wow, looks like I should have RTFM ;-) Works like a charm, and saved me from editing 673 posts by hand. Thanks a lot!